# Installed programs in Ubuntu wont launch

Tags: gnome

I have tried installing several programs in Ubuntu 16.04 from Ubuntu software. They install, but when I try to launch them, the launching fails. 
It happened first to me with Kturtle programming game, and then with GNOME Chess and gnuchess.  (GNOME Chess, though installed, doesnt even appear in computer when searched for).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have a similar problem on Ubuntu 18.04, with several program such as Carnet (note-taking app) or Rambox (a multiple-messenger managment app). I have installed them through SNAP and when I click on "launch" nothing happens. When I try to launch them from the start menu, nothing happens either. It is as if they are not really installed, even though I had no message telling me that something went wrong with the installation.